# phpMyAdmin SQL returns "Current selection does not contain a unique column."

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've been using this query for years without any issues. Now today I try to run it and I get "Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available." and I cannot figure out why.

```
SELECT requests.id,
contacts.doctors_name,
contacts.office,
contacts.first_name,
contacts.last_name,
contacts.address_1,
contacts.address_2,
contacts.city,
contacts.state,
contacts.zip,
contacts.phone,
contacts.email,
dealers.name,
dealers.city,
dealers.state,
dealers.po_number,
DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ(requests.date_created, '+00:00', '-05:00'), '%m/%d/%Y %h:%i %p') AS created,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT products.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS name,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT products.serial_number SEPARATOR ', ') AS serialNumber,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT products.repair_issue SEPARATOR ', ') AS repairIssue,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT products.during_use SEPARATOR ', ') AS duringUse,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT products.patient_injured SEPARATOR ', ') AS patientInjured
FROM contacts, requests, products, dealers
WHERE contacts.id=requests.contact_id
AND dealers.id=requests.dealer_id
AND requests.id=products.web_ref_number
AND requests.date_created between '2023-07-01 00:00:00' and '2023-10-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY requests.id
```